How to chain iterators dynamically?
I need to build repeating sequences of characters which have to look like

'level' 0:
'x', 'a',  'a',... 'b', 'b'...,'x', 'a',  'a',... 'b', 'b'...,

'level' 1:
'x', 'x', 'a',  'a',... 'b', 'b'...,'x', ... 'a',  'a',... 'b', 'b'..., 'x', 'x', 'a',  'a',..


It can rather simply be coded for a given level with nested iterators:
fn level_n(next: impl Iterator<Item = char> + Clone) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + Clone {
    repeat(once('x').chain(next))
        .take(10 as usize)
        .flat_map(|v| v)
}

And then:
level_n(level_n(level_n(level_0(2))))
    .cycle()
    .take(2000)
    .collect::<Vec<char>>();

Playground
But I can't figure out how to chain them dynamically for arbitrary n. This should look like:
let v = (0..3)
    .fold(level_0(3), |a, i| level_n(a))
    .cycle()
    .take(2000)
    .collect::<Vec<char>>();

It doesn't work because types are different, plus cycle requires its iterator to be Clone so can't keep it in a builder struct.
ps - here is a lame workaround by giving up on Clone and opting to collect/into_iter (iter.cloned didn't work either).

I don't understand the description of the sequences you want to achieve.

it's for https://leetcode.com/problems/lexicographical-numbers/ - should be digits in lexicographical order. But it's really not important for the question - I've met same problem before and also had to opt for a wierd workaround not being able to chain/build iterators.

You could try a recursive function instead of a fold?

not sure if I did it right, but I tried this
fn rec_level_n(next:impl Iterator<Item=Option> + Clone + 'static, level:usize) -> impl Iterator<Item=Option> + Clone{
if level > 0 {
rec_level_n(repeat(once(None).chain( next )).take(10 as usize).flat_map(|v| v), level-1)
} else {
next
}
}
and it doesn't compile

perhaps the proper rusty way would be to use procedural macros... but I'm afraid they won't work on leetcode and alike

You could try emulating a Box<dyn Iterator<Item = char> + Clone> indirectly:
trait CloneCharIter: Iterator<Item = char> {
    fn do_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneCharIter>;
}
impl<T: Iterator<Item = char> + Clone + 'static> CloneCharIter for T {
    fn do_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneCharIter> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
impl Clone for Box<dyn CloneCharIter> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.as_ref().do_clone()
    }
}

fn level_0(p: usize) -> Box<dyn CloneCharIter> {
    Box::new(
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(move |c| repeat(c).take(p)),
    )
}

fn level_n(next: Box<dyn CloneCharIter>) -> Box<dyn CloneCharIter> {
    Box::new(
        repeat(once('x').chain(next))
            .take(10 as usize)
            .flat_map(|v| v),
    )
}

let v = (0..3)
    .fold(level_0(3), |a, _| level_n(a))
    .cycle()
    .take(2000)
    .collect::<Vec<char>>();

(playground)

yess!! thank you very much! I've actually tried implementing custom Iter + Clone having found few similar advises but it was failing with stack overflow as I've forgotten about  as_ref in self.as_ref().do_clone() . Now it works.
